# Different button based on DB entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I am working on this website where I want a button for "Add to favorite" and if you have already pressed the "Add to favorite" it should show the "Remove from favorite"

It wont show the "Add to favorite" but only the "Remove from favorite" if its in the SQL db..

I assume it's something with my "else" code.

Here's my code for this:

```
$tbl_name="favorit";
$usrname=$_SESSION['UserIN'];

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$usrname' AND type='drink'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$isadmin=$rows['typeid'];

if($isadmin===$idno){
echo '<a class="btn" href="../includes/sletfavoritdrink.php?drink='.$idno.'">Fjern fra favorit</a>';

} else {

echo '<a class="btn" href="../includes/favoritdrink.php?drink='.$idno.'">Tilføj til favorit</a>';

}}
```

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Where are you setting `$idno`?

Comment: You probably want a double equals here instead of a triple: `if($isadmin==$idno){`

Comment: $idno is in the top: $idno=$_GET['id'];

Comment: Have you echoed out `$isadmin` & `$idno` to make sure they match?

Comment: Yes they do match, the only problem is that it wont show the link "Tilføj til favorit" when there isnt a record in the DB
However if I run the script which will add the drink to my favorites, it does show the "Fjern fra favorit"

Comment: Could you try the `if/else` in reverse? Echo `Tilføj til favorit` first if `$isadmin!=$idno`, and then - `Fjern fra favorit` as the else.  `if($isadmin!=$idno){echo '<a class="btn" href="../includes/favoritdrink.php?drink='.$idno.'">Tilføj til favorit</a>';} else { echo '<a class="btn" href="../includes/sletfavoritdrink.php?drink='.$idno.'">Fjern fra favorit</a>';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your if() statement is inside the while() loop that iterates over the result set, neither condition will be run when there's no result set to iterate over. So, if the user doesn't have a favorite drink then the query returns an empty result set and the while loop never runs a single iteration.

You're essentially doing this:

```
foreach row in the set {
    if condition then
        branch 1
    else
        branch 2
}
```

But there's nothing in the set, so the if() never runs. You could do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    // user has a favorite, show "remove" button
} else {
    // user doesn't have a favorite, show "add" button
}
```

Also note, the mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO.